# unable to launch camera with getLaunchIntentForPackage()

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing my own android-launcher now, and it seems to work fine so far.
I can launch every application except for the Camera.

I am creating a new intent:

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.camera");
```

And the intent is not `null`.
But when i start the intent with

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```

my application crashes.
LogCat:

```
12-28 17:18:43.711: I/Launch(4166): Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.camera/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity }
12-28 17:18:43.711: D/AndroidRuntime(4166): Shutting down VM
12-28 17:18:43.711: W/dalvikvm(4166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
12-28 17:18:43.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 17:18:43.731: E/AndroidRuntime(4166): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I know I could use

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setCompomponent(new ComponentName(args));
```

But I have no idea which arguments i can use to start a different application.

The solution should work for every package name, and not using a special cameraIntent.

Hope anyone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working myself. What I did is watching the LogCat while tapping the camera icon in GO Launcher EX. In the log i found this line:

```
12-30 17:38:19.098: I/ActivityManager(1375): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.camera/.CameraEntry bnds=[300,710][372,800] } from pid 11644
```

and I put that into an intent, with an if-block around and some trys and catches:

```
String packageName = "com.android.camera"; //Or whatever package should be launched

if(packageName.equals("com.android.camera")){ //Camera
    try{
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.camera");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CameraEntry");
        intent.setComponent(comp);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
else{ //Any other
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: and this not right to ask question i think you just combine my answer and comment for making your on answer

Answer (score 1):

try as using `getInstalledPackages`:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();  
 // PackageManager
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm  
           .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);  
 ArrayList<String> arrpackname=new ArrayList<String>();
 for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {  

   if(pi.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("camera") &&
              pi.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("android") ){

     Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pi.packageName); 

     if (intent != null)  
       startActivity(intent);  

    }
 }
```

OR you can try as:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent();

ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.camera",
                                           "com.android.camera.Camera");

mIntent.setComponent(comp);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

mIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");

startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: I use exactly this method to get the packagenames from all applications. The problem is, that my application crashes when I try to launch the camera.

Comment: @Lars : no you are trying different . first try my answer then let me known what happen and i will give you other solution

Comment: Ok, I tried it aaaand it crashed.12-28 19:13:14.774: E/AndroidRuntime(5840): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.hobbycoder.android.test/net.hobbycoder.android.test.TestActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Lars : it's working or not? if no then first check your camera Activity name by just launching camera app and watch logcat to found default application package name and activity name

Comment: @Lars : we have two ways for starting any activity as i have mention in my answer . maybe you have any other issue

Comment: Aha. I ran the code on the emulator and it worked. Seems to be some kind of bug on my htc desire s.

Answer (score 0):

and why not try with the code that is to capture images?

```
capturePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            }
        });
```

I could work the same way or want to call the camera app by default?

Comment: Because I don't want a special cameraIntent. I want to launch **any** application with just knowing the package name. That works fine unless I try to start the camera.